# Showing Multiple rows against an ID in One Row - Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, pivot, transpose

My question is somewhat related to :
[Display multiple values of a column in one row (SQL Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508078/display-multiple-values-of-a-column-in-one-row-sql-oracle)

However, I could not achieve desired results. Following is my Problem Statement;

**I have a SQL Query ;**

```
SELECT initiator_msisdn,  trx_type  || '/'  || SUM(trx_amt/100)  || '/'  || SUM(merchant_comm_amt/100) agent_data
FROM LBI_DM_MK.T_M_INTERNAL_AUDIT_D
WHERE DATA_DATE = '20180401'
AND trx_status  ='Completed'
GROUP BY initiator_msisdn,  trx_type
;
```

**That returns these rows;**

[image]

The SQL That brings this data is ;

But, I want following result.

[image]

**Please help to sort out this issue;**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `LISTAGG`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT initiator_msisdn,
          trx_type  || '/'  || SUM(trx_amt/100)  || '/'  ||
          SUM(merchant_comm_amt/100) agent_data
  FROM LBI_DM_MK.T_M_INTERNAL_AUDIT_D
  WHERE DATA_DATE = '20180401'
    AND trx_status  ='Completed'
  GROUP BY initiator_msisdn,  trx_type
)
SELECT initiator_msisdn,
       LISTAGG(agent_data, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY agent_data) AS agent_data
FROM cte
GROUP BY initiator_msisdn;
```

Comment: I also managed to do it with same function meanwhile :) 

here is the result 

SELECT initiator_msisdn,    LISTAGG(agent_data, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY agent_data) "grp"
FROM (
SELECT initiator_msisdn,  trx_type  || ':'  || SUM(trx_amt/100)  || '/'  || SUM(merchant_comm_amt/100) agent_data
FROM LBI_DM_MK.T_M_INTERNAL_AUDIT_D
WHERE DATA_DATE = '20180401'
AND trx_status  ='Completed'
GROUP BY initiator_msisdn,   trx_type
)
GROUP BY initiator_msisdn;